# What is the simplest technique for echoing out a PDO object inside of a foreach?

Tags: php

I'm making my first application for practice over this delightful weekend. This is where I'm currently at and am trying to figure out if there is a better technique then all of the `business->$column_name` that I'm doing and jumping in and out of PHP.

```
$sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM companies ORDER BY state ASC');
$results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

**html code snipped for space**

<?php foreach($results as $business): ?>
<p>
<strong><?php echo $business->name; ?></strong><br />
<?php echo $business->city . ', ' . $business->state; ?><br />
Call <?php echo $business->phone; ?><br />
<!-- needs to check if website & twitter are present -->
<?php
if (isset($business->twitter)) {
echo 'Follow us on Twitter <a href="http://twitter.com/' . $business->twitter . '">@' . $business->twitter . '</a>';
}
?>
</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Is there a way to clean some of this up? Especially when I get into the website and twitter stuff and have to do the `href` followed by the text it just feels messy to me.

Answer (score -1):

For something as trivial as this, I often just echo out string literals for HTML.  Also, don't forget `htmlspecialchars()` around variable data to make sure your HTML is valid, and you don't end up with potential XSS attacks.

```
foreach ($result as $business);
echo '<p>',
     '<strong>', htmlspecialchars($business->name), '</strong><br/>',
     htmlspecialchars($business->city), ', ', htmlspecialchars($business->state),
// ... etc
```

A better option for anything not so simple is to use a templating engine such as [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

```
$smarty->assign('business', $business');
```

Then in your template you can use:

```
<p>
    <strong>{$business->name}</strong><br/>
    {$business->city}, {$business->state}
    {* etc *}
```

Just remember that if you use a templating engine, there is added overhead.  That's why I don't bother with it small one-off tasks.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend echoing the HTML. The way he does it is much cleaner IMO. It also allows for syntax highlighting for the HTML, which would otherwise be treated simply as strings.

Comment: It's a trivial amount of HTML.  You don't need syntax highlighting.  For bigger stuff, a template engine should be used.

Comment: I don't agree. It's also much harder to correctly indent HTML if you echo it (unless you echo it in an unnatural way). The way he does it is best.

Comment: What are you talking about?  You should be indenting code to make it useful to you.  You can indent code no matter what method you use.  Unless you are talking about indenting HTML on output... in that case, what for?  Ideally your HTML would be minified before being sent to the client anyway.

Comment: I'm obviously talking about indenting HTML. You may not care about it, but many of people do. Your "solution" has much more disadvantages than advantages.

Comment: Of course I care about indenting my code... to make it readable and clear.  That's the whole purpose of indenting your code.  You have yet to name a single disadvantage to my answer that makes any sense.  Please either clarify what your problem with it is, or take your comments elsewhere.

Comment: Loss of readability; lack of syntax highlighting; having to escape characters; less efficient.

Comment: My suggestion **adds** readability, syntax highlighting for a couple tags is not important (at least not to me), I don't see how having to escape characters is a problem, and it certainly isn't less efficient.  Perhaps it isn't clear what I am suggesting.  I will edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Most people agree it's less readable, look for similar questions here on Stack Overflow. Syntax highlighting is always a plus, not having it is always a minus. Having to escape characters is not a "problem", but it's certainly a disadvantage. And it certainly is less efficient: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php